# How can you determine how much disk space a DB2 table is using?

Tags: db2, aix

Is there a query that I could run on a DB2 instance running on AIX that would show much how much disk space a specific table is using?

DB2/AIX64 10.1.2

Comment: Don't forget to include the indexes of the table.  They're taking up disk space too.  [How to check tablespace utilization in DB2 V9](http://www.dbatodba.com/db2/db2-udb-v9/how-to-check-tablespace-utilization-in-db2-v9).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to query the `ADMIN_GET_TAB_INFO` table function:

```
SELECT 
 data_object_p_size + 
 index_object_p_size + 
 long_object_p_size + 
 lob_object_p_size + 
 xml_object_p_size 
FROM TABLE (SYSPROC.ADMIN_GET_TAB_INFO('YOURSCHEMA', 'YOURTABLE'))
```